# DataContractSerializer sets all class attributes to null after deserialization

Tags: c#, deserialization

i successfully serialized a List of objects. Now i need to deserialize it again. I noticed that it only deserialize the list. The attributes of the items are all null.

Example:

serialized xml:

```
<ArrayOfLevel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
    <Level>
        <size>0</size>
        <difficulty>1</difficulty>
        <title>OverTheHill</title>
    </Level>
</ArrayOfLevel>
```

deserialization:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "test.xml"), FileMode.Open);

XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Level>));        

List<Level> loaded = (List<Level>)serializer.ReadObject(reader, true);

reader.Close();
stream.Close();

foreach (Level level in loaded)
{
    Debug.Log(level.title);
}
```

Level class

```
public class Level
{
    public int size;
    public int difficulty;
    public string title;
}
```

This logs null in the console. I can't see where the problem is. The code runs inside Unity in C#

Comment: Can we see anything that would allow us to repro? what is `Level`? and `Level.title`?

Comment: Level is just a class with an int called size, an int called difficulty and a string called title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me with your xml (after it failed in the way you described originally):

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
{
    List<Level> loaded = (List<Level>)serializer.ReadObject(reader, true);
    System.Console.WriteLine(loaded.Single().title);
}
```

I suggest simply losing the `XmlDictionaryReader` / `XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas`

Note that I'm using:

```
[DataContract]
public class Level
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public int size { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int difficulty { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

as the object definition.

Comment: Thank you! i figuered out that i was missing the [DataContract] at the top thanks to your code